# Как браузеры распознают XSS атаки? Есть какие либо чёткие алгоритмы?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, безопасность, xss

Вопрос задан в контексте поля заголовка ответа `X-XSS-Protection`.

Судя по [поддержке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) FireFox подобного функционала не имеет вообще.

Comment: Проверяет скрипт на безопасность

Comment: Я хотел бы узнать какие то более чёткие сведения. В частности я видел пример как Chrome блокировал страницу которая из GET запроса генерировала DOM элемент, например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## IE8

В IE8 XSS Filter основан на симуляции работы JavaScript до того, как данные передадутся на выполнение токеназеру HTML и реальному JavaScript.

[image: IE8]

- это довольно медленно
- дает [ложные срабатывания фильтра](http://www.collinjackson.com/research/xssauditor.pdf)
- не всегда срабатывает (не срабатывает: использоваение UTF-7; трюки вроде `<a<img/src/onerror=alert(1)//<` и другие)

Без разбора HTML проанализировать и найти спрятанные XSS в таком виде довольно трудно:

[image: response]

По перечисленным причинам в IE8 данные с того же сайта (same-origin) загружаются без фильтрации.

Многие крупные сайты (Google, YouTube, Blogger) отключают `X-XSS-Protection`, используя серверные механизмы защиты от XSS.

## Chrome

Правильный способ найти XSS - работать с уже распарсенным DOM:

[image: правильный способ]

В [Chrome используется XSSAuditor](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Features/XSS_Filter), который перехватывает вызовы JavaScript, поэтому точность срабатывания у него выше, чем у механизма IE8:

[image: XSS Auditor]

Подробное понимание работы защиты описано в [исходном коде xss_auditor](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/parser/xss_auditor.cc), в комментариях к нему разъяснено, как это работает, например в описании `TruncateForSrcLikeAttribute` и `TruncateForScriptLikeAttribute`.

Увы, более подробных сведений, кроме кода, я не нашел.

## Firefox: расширение "NoScript Security Suite"

[Плагин](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) просто блокирует весь JavaScript, который не проходит по белому списку (поведение гибко настраивается). C `X-XSS-Protection` плагин не связан. При анализе JavaScript используются те же подходы, что и в XSS Auditor.

### Ссылки

- [Проект OWASP: заголовки безопасности](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Headers_Project)
- [Пример блокировки](http://www.enhanceie.com/test/xss/)

## Простые правила: как избежать XSS

Перефразировал "чего не следует делать чтобы случайно не попасть под фильтр" в "как избежать XSS". Это не тождество, так как еще существуют ложные положительные и ложные отрицательные случаи.

- Правило #0 - Никогда и нигде не вставляйте непроверенные данные (объединяет правила 1-5)
- Правило #1 - Экранируйте HTML содержимое: `<div>...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...</div>`
- Правило #2 - Экранируйте HTML атрибуты: `<div attr="...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...">content</div>`
- Правило #3 - Экранируйте данные в JavaScript: `<script>alert('...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...')</script>`
- Правило #3.1 - Экранируйте JSON в HTML и читайте эти данные с помощью JSON.parse
- Правило #4 - Проверяйте и экранируйте данные перед вставкой CSS в HTML: `<style>selector { property : ...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...; } </style>`
- Правило #5 - Экранируйте URL: `<a href="http://www.somesite.com?test=...ESCAPE UNTRUSTED DATA BEFORE PUTTING HERE...">link</a>`
- Правило #6 - Очищайте разметку HTML с помощью предназначенных для этого библиотек
- Правило #7 - Предотвращайте XSS на основе DOM
- Бонусное правило #1: Используйте HTTPOnly куки (они станут не доступны в JavaScript)
- Бонусное правило #2: Используйте политику безопасности контента `Content-Security-Policy`
- Бонусное правило #3: Используйте шаблонизаторы, которые автоматически экранируют данные (для PHP я использую `Twig`)
- Бонусное правило #4: Используйте заголовок `X-XSS-Protection`

### Ссылки:

- [Рекомендации OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Bonus_Rule_.234:_Use_the_X-XSS-Protection_Response_Header)
- [XSS, основанные на DOM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: А нет каких нибудь простых рекомендаций чего не следует делать чтобы случайно не попасть под фильтр?

Comment: Перефразировал "чего не следует делать чтобы случайно не попасть под фильтр" в "как избежать XSS" и добавил этот раздел