# Показать содержимое после 3 параграфа PHP

Tags: php

Статья разбита параграфами есть задумка вставить похожий контент, но только через 3 параграфа. Как в php можно сделать понять никак не могу.

Comment: Можете более точно описать проблему, из Вашего вопроса ничего не понятно

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, добавьте пример кода и дополнительную информацию. Что вы сделали, для решения данной проблемы? Это не сайт фриланса

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно такое решение вы искали:

```
$content = [
    '<div>Контент после 1-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 2-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 3-их трёх параграфов</div>',
];

$str = '<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>';

preg_match_all('~<p>.*?</p>~', $str, $arr);

foreach ($arr[0] ?? [] as $k => $item) {
    if ((++$k % 3) == 0) {
        echo $item . current($content);
        next($content);
    } else {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

---

Для версии PHP >= 5.6:

```
$content = [
    '<div>Контент после 1-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 2-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 3-их трёх параграфов</div>',
];

$str = '<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>';

preg_match_all('~<p>.*?</p>~', $str, $arr);
$arr = empty($arr[0]) ? [] : $arr[0];

foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    if ((++$k % 3) == 0) {
        echo $item . current($content);
        next($content);
    } else {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нравится. Как коммент: использовать регулярку вместо токеназера - не всегда будет работать `<p class="foo">` уже не найдет. И будет путать с комментами в HTML `<!--`.

Comment: @TotalPusher регулярку можно же  "подкрутить" :)

Comment: Да, для ТС такого варианта будет достаточно. Для исключения случаев `<!--` и `<script> ... "<p>" `регулярку не составите

Comment: @TotalPusher вы имеете ввиду вложенные, а также "не правильно" `(типа такого: <scr<p>ipt>)` написанные теги? Не ради спора, но хотел бы отметить, что регулярки довольно мощный инструмент.

Comment: Да. Это и имею в виду. Например, фильтр от уязвимостей в IE8+ [работает на основе регулярок](http://www.collinjackson.com/research/xssauditor.pdf) и "пропускает". [мой недавний ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822593/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-xss-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B/822915#822915)

Comment: Премного благодарен вам! Но желательно бы для php 5.6

Comment: @Позитивонлайн дописал код в ответ.